# Teams meeting option doesn't appear in New items tab in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams, outlook-addin

I have microsoft teams add-in installed in outlook, but for some reason the option Teams meeting doesn't appear under new items tab.

TS:

1. Checked addins option in outlook and Add-in for Teams is there but when I tick it and restart Outlook, it appear again unticked.
2. There is different version of addin specified in outlook then it is in real in appdata location.
   [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezhgi.png) in real there is version 1.0.22062.1
3. Section teams appears with option Share to Teams [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTe7Q.png)

Comment: If you click New Appointment first, is there a Teams Meeting button on the ribbon bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you  checked th disabled add-in?

Go to **File > Options > Add-ins**

If the Teams Meeting Add-in is listed in the Disabled Application Add-ins list.

**under Manage**, select **disabled items**, and then select Go….

[image]

enable the Microsoft Teams Meeting Add-in for Microsoft Office

**under Manage**, select **COM Add-ins**, and then select Go….

Select the Microsoft Teams Meeting Add-in for Microsoft Office checkbox.

Choose OK on all dialog boxes, and then close Outlook.

Restart Outlook.

If that doesn’t work, or if you’re not on Windows 10, try downloading and running the [Microsoft Support Recovery Assistant](https://aka.ms/SaRA_Home) to perform automated troubleshooting steps and fixes.

Besides, you can try other troubleshooting steps in this official document:
[Teams Meeting add-in in Outlook for Windows does not show](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-add-in-for-outlook#:%7E:text=Teams%20Meeting%20add%2Din%20in%20Outlook%20for%20Windows%20does%20not%20show)

If you think my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer to help other people.